# Determine the most suitable datatype for text column in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Given, that I have a table with string column (VARCHAR(...)), that contains different values, like:

```
a
b
NULL
1
```

or

```
2
4
2023-01-01
```

***The problem***

I want to determine the most precise data type, that I can use to store these information in the following way:

- The first example should return VARCHAR, as this is the only type suitable to store records
- The second example should return also VARCHAR, IF!!! we consider all rows, however, if I specify the first two row, returns NUMBER

Comment: if the data is not rigid, you should ether just use TEXT/VARCHAR or VARIANT, the former has the advantage of being the input type to all the `TRY_TO_` parse functions. The only reason to have the data in a type field is to JOIN or ORDER in a context that matters. But if you do not have a context, why pretend you do.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to try cast it to stuff you care about:

```
with data(set_id, text) as (
    select *
    from values
        (1, 'a'),
        (1, 'b'),
        (1, NULL),
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (2, '4'),
        (2, '2023-01-01'),
        (3, '2'),
        (3, '4')
)
select set_id
    ,text
    ,try_to_date(text, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as d1
    ,try_to_number(text) as d2
from data;
```

[image]

then to count the classifications:

```
with data(set_id, text) as (
    select *
    from values
        (1, 'a'),
        (1, 'b'),
        (1, NULL),
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (2, '4'),
        (2, '2023-01-01'),
        (3, '2'),
        (3, '4')
), cast as (
    select set_id
        ,text
        ,try_to_date(text, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as d1
        ,try_to_number(text) as d2
    from data
)
select set_id
    ,count(d1) as c_d1
    ,count(d2) as c_d2
    ,count(text) as c_t
from cast
group by 1
```

[image]

- set 1 has both things that are text ct > d2 and things that are number d2 > 1 thus should be text.
- set 2 the above rule holds, but also it has dates, and numbers.
- set 3 has numbers of the same count as non-null entries, so could be numbers.

```
with data(set_id, text) as (
    select *
    from values
        (1, 'a'),
        (1, 'b'),
        (1, NULL),
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (2, '4'),
        (2, '2023-01-01'),
        (3, '2'),
        (3, '4')
), cast as (
    select set_id
        ,text
        ,try_to_date(text, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as d1
        ,try_to_number(text) as d2
    from data
), counted as (
    select set_id
        ,count(d1) as c_d1
        ,count(d2) as c_d2
        ,count(text) as c_t
    from cast
    group by 1
)
select set_id
    ,case 
        when c_d2 > 0 and c_d2 = c_t then 'number'
        when c_d2 > 0 and c_d2 < c_t then 'text'
        else 'text'
    end as classifed
from counted;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments,

In the meantime, I have found a Snowflake method

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/infer_schema

which is doing exactly what I want